How do I show the existence and uniqueness of second order linear differential equations using Picards' Theorem?
My course left the proof of this theorem out of the notes. So I am requesting that somebody help me finish it.
I want to prove the existence of the linear second order differential equation $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are "continuous" functions.
Here is where there is not much clarity. I am guessing that $y', y$ are actually functions of $x$, and hence $y'' = -p(x)y' - q(x)y$ is a function of $x$, so we have $y''(x) = f(x, y'(x), y(x))$, where $y'(x), y(x)$ are variables?.
Then you make a substition $y' = z$, and so $z'(x) = f(x, z(x), y(x))$. How can Picards' theorem then be applied?
My guess is that if we define $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ to be $g(x, z(x)) = f(x, z(x), y(x))$ where $g$ is Lipschitz continuous in $z$? Is this valid because once we know $z$ we know $y$ if the initial values are given? The equation can be written in terms of $x$ and $z(x)$ it will just contain integrals. What are the conditions here? How do you show Lipshitz continuity?

You were halfway there. For the application of Picard-Lindelöf you need a first-order system. However the state dimension is arbitrary for the theorem, so you can construct the state so it fits the given problem. The equations so far are
$$
y'=z\\
z'=f(x,z,y),
$$
which nicely suggests $u=[y,z]$ as the state. The Lipschitz constant for the system can be constructed from the Lipschitz constant of $f$, how close that is depends on the vector norm you chose to employ.

Now I see why they left the proof out of textbook. I have no clue what "state" is, do you know of any textbooks that define this concept?

Time-state is just a fancy name for the directions or components of the domain $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n$. State is just the collection of positions and other variables of the dynamical system.
